# Property Change not showing in Visual Studio designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, properties, user-controls

Using VS2015 I'm adding some custom functionality to a TextBlock for a small app and, since I can't derive from TextBlock itself (it's sealed), I'm deriving from UserControl.

In my xaml file, I have

```
<TextBlock x:Name="innerText"/>
```

As the only element within the usercontrol.

In my code-behind, I have the following used for accessing the text:

```
public string Label
{
    get { return innerText.Text; }
    set {
        if (value != innerText.Text)
        {
            innerText.Text = value;
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Label"));
        }
    }
}
```

This works great when I'm running my app. On other pages, I am able to add instances of the control and set the "Label" property correctly. Unfortunately, the value of the "Label" property doesn't carry through to the inner textbox within the designer itself.

How can I get the value to update in the designer? While not strictly necessary (as I said, at run-time it works fine), it would make layout in the designer much easier for me.

Update:
I also tried using a DependencyProperty, with the same issue. Run-time works great, design-time shows nothing.

```
public string Label
{
    get { return GetValue(LabelProperty).ToString(); ; }
    set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(AutoSizingText), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

And then, in the xaml, I set the DataContext for the entire control:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

And tried to bind the Text value:

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" />
```

Comment: At design time, you have not initialized the value of TextBlock. Set the value as <TextBlock Text="some hardcoded val" ..../>. Or through binding.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using a DependencyProperty and binding to it, and I had the same issue... Works great at run-time, doesn't show anything at design-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a [dependency property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms734499(v=vs.90).aspx) instead of relying on setting the `innerText` element's `Text` property. A dependency property will behave just like any other property on a control, including updating in design mode.

```
public string Label
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Label.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(MyClassName), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```

And your XAML will look like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="usr" ...>
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label, ElementName=usr}" ... />
    ...
</UserControl>
```

*Pro tip: Type `propdp`, then `Tab, Tab` to quickly create a dependency property.*

Here's an example usage:

```
<local:MyUserControl Label="Le toucan has arrived"/>
```

**Note**: You do not need to set the `DataContext` to `Self` when using a dependency property, this will generally screw things up as the `UserControl` should not set it's own `DataContext`, the parent control should.

Comment: Thanks, adding a name to the control and referencing it via ElementName did the trick!

Comment: Actually, it means that all elements on a page (I have a few dozen) now reference the last item created, probably because they all have the same name :/

I'll play around with that a bit more.

Comment: It sounds to me like they all share the same `DataContext`.

Comment: Just at design-time, though. At run-time it works perfectly.

Comment: Do you have some design-time only data that could be presenting the same item over and over? You could try rebuilding, or closing/opening the view file. Even restarting Visual Studio might help.